User Install of Google Chrome
how do I uninstall a user install google chrome in there appdata folder. the users are not allowed to uninstall their own software and I really don't want to op the users and then have them uninstall their own software. there has got to be another way. I've tried things like revo but how would I target something without them being logged in.

i tried installing google chrome enterprise but it didnt get rid of the user install

Have you tried to simply delete the chrome user profile directory?

You should be talking with your IT support staff. If you are a user on your computer, we really cannot and should not help you here.

you can run a script to delete the google profile in the app data folder
Commend prompt
rd "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"

you can set the script to run at startup or any given time with task scheduler , or set a group policy to do so if you are managing the users via active directory.
Additionally you can set a group policy to prevent users from running specific programs
